# Как сделать, чтобы выделение шло на всю ширину, а не только на ту ширину, в которую вмещаются слова

Tags: html, css

Как сделать, чтобы выделение шло на всю ширину блока, а не только на ту ширину, в которую вмещаются слова.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

CSS код саб меню, то есть всплывающего при наведении.

```css
    .topmenu > li > a.active, 
    .submenu a:hover {
      color: #fff;
    }
    .topmenu .fa, 
    .submenu .fa {
      margin-left: 5px;
      color: inherit;
    }
    .submenu {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 5;
      min-width: 200px;
      background: white;
      border-top: 1px solid #CBCBCC;
      border-left: 1px solid #CBCBCC;
      border-right: 1px solid #CBCBCC;
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0; 
      transform-origin: 0% 0%;
      transform: rotateX(-90deg);
      transition: .3s linear;  
    }
    .submenu li {position: relative;}
    .submenu li a {
      color: #282828;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      font-size: 13px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #CBCBCC;
    }
    .submenu .submenu {
      position: absolute;
      left: 100%;
      top: -1px;
      transition: .3s linear;
    }
    nav li:hover > .submenu {
      transform: rotateX(0deg);
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="menu">
   <div class="left-logo">
    
   </div>
   <div class="main-menu">
    
   
   <nav>
    <ul class="topmenu">
     <li><a href="">Главная</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="">Услуги</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
       <li><a href="">Лечебно-оздоровительный массаж</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Стрижка</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="">О нас</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Также есть код основного меню, если надо будет, я его прикреплю.

Comment: Сделайте нужные елементы на всю ширину род. блока.

Comment: Спасибо. Добавил width:100%; в .submenu li a{width:100%;}

Answer (score 0):

Надо поставить свойство `display: block`.

```css
.topmenu > li > a.active, 
    .submenu a:hover {
      color: #fff;
    }
    .topmenu .fa, 
    .submenu .fa {
      margin-left: 5px;
      color: inherit;
    }
    .submenu {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 5;
      min-width: 200px;
      background: white;
      border-top: 1px solid #CBCBCC;
      border-left: 1px solid #CBCBCC;
      border-right: 1px solid #CBCBCC;
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0; 
      transform-origin: 0% 0%;
      transform: rotateX(-90deg);
      transition: .3s linear;  
    }
    .submenu li {position: relative;}
    .submenu li a {
      color: #282828;
      padding: 10px 20px;

      display: block;
      font-size: 13px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #CBCBCC;
    }
    .submenu .submenu {
      position: absolute;
      left: 100%;
      top: -1px;
      transition: .3s linear;
    }
    nav li:hover > .submenu {
      transform: rotateX(0deg);
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
<div class="menu">
   <div class="left-logo">
    
   </div>
   <div class="main-menu">
    
   
   <nav>
    <ul class="topmenu">
     <li><a href="">Главная</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="">Услуги</a>
       <ul class="submenu">
       <li><a href="">Лечебно-оздоровительный массаж</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Стрижка</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="">О нас</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
   </div>
  </div>
```